# aws cli assume-role works but still get permission denied on s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I am trying to access an s3 bucket in account A from account B.

I followed [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/) Cross-account IAM roles option. Then, to assume the role I use this aws cli command in my code:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::*********:role/cross-account-s3-access" --role-session-name AWSCLI-Session
```

I can see that the role was assumed:

```
{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "********",
        "SecretAccessKey": "********",
        "SessionToken": "********",
        "Expiration": "2021-07-29T08:46:33Z"
    },
"AssumedRoleUser": {
    "AssumedRoleId": "********:AWSCLI-Session",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::********:assumed-role/cross-account-s3-access/AWSCLI-Session"
    }
}
```

Then, to check if the cross-account access worked, I perform the following command which return access denied:

```
+ aws s3 ls s3://digibank-endofday-files-stg
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

My question is what is the **--role-session-name** flag? I probably put a wrong value but I couldn't find a proper explanation about it. Where do I find value of it??

Comment: the value is basically free-text, should not have any impact on anything. What permissions does the assumed role have?

Comment: Did you somehow make use of the credentials that were returned? You could put them in a new configuration with `aws configure --profile assumed-role`. Or, you can put the IAM Role ARN in the AWS CLI configuration file and it will assume it for you: [Switching to an IAM role (AWS CLI) - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-cli.html)

Comment: You have to use `Credentials` given to you by `aws sts assume-role`.

Comment: @luk2302 The permissions the assumed role has are: "ListAllMyBuckets", "ListBucket", "GetBucketLocation", "GetObject", "PutObject"

Comment: @Marcin What to I need to do with those credentials? Where do I need to put them?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm afraid I didn't do any further use with the credentials I got. Do I need to put another `aws` command after the command I am using now?

Answer (score 3):

The flow is:

- Using permanent credentials (eg from your IAM User), call `AssumeRole()` and provide the ARN of the desired role
- If you have permission to call AssumeRole on this role, AWS STS will return a set of temporary credentials
- You will then need to **use those credentials in subsequent calls to AWS services**

So, future calls will not be made from your IAM User (since it does *not* have permission to access S3). Instead, the call will need to be made with the new credentials.

If you were using a programming language, you would use these credentials to make a new `Session` object and then use it to make API calls.

However, given that you are using the AWS CLI, the easiest method to assume the call is to add a configuration in your `~/.aws/config` file similar to this:

```
[profile prodaccess]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/ProductionAccessRole
source_profile = default
```

This configuration is saying: "Use my credentials from the *default* profile to assume this IAM Role".

You can use it like this:

```
aws s3 ls s3://digibank-endofday-files-stg --profile prodaccess
```

For details, see: [Switching to an IAM role (AWS CLI) - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-cli.html)

The AWS CLI will automatically call `AssumeRole()`, then make the requested call using the temporary credentials that were returned.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer. This is all making sense but one thing is that all what I described happenes as a cronjob on a pod. So I cannot manually create configuration file, I need to create it automatically from the code in such a way that each time the cronjob runs this configuration file will be created with the given credentials. When you do `aws configure` you have to manually insert those credentials.

Comment: You could call AssumeRole, extract the provided credentials and then store them in Environment variables. For an example, see: [iam-assume-role.sh](https://gist.github.com/ambakshi/ba0fe456bb6da24da7c2). By the way, next time please put full information in your Question -- you never mentioned cron or a pod. It is always a good idea to mention _why_ you are doing something rather than just _how_, so that people can provide a more-appropriate answer.